# Liquid-XML Editor Line Numbers for text files

Tags: liquid-xml

I am able to open large files and it works great, however I do not get line numbers even though that option is on by default.  It does for xml files, but a text file with .xml extension does not.

Any ideas on how to get the line numbers or maybe the software is not meant to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The Large File Editor does not display line numbers.

It does have the concept of lines, so you can move to a specific line using menu Edit->Go to... (Ctrl+G).

Depending on your PCs specification, you may be able to open larger files without invoking the Large File Editor, please see:

[Opening Large XML Documents in Liquid XML Studio](https://support.liquid-technologies.com/kb/a105/opening-large-xml-documents.aspx)